# Eclipselink and JPA bug, unknown entity type

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x

I´m having problems with eclipselink in every version along with JPA and Weblogic. It seems to be a non-resolved bug.

The configuration I´m using is Kepler, Weblogic 10.3.5 and Eclipselink 2.1.

The error it throws is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: <object> is not a known entity type.
```

I already have all the types declared in the persistence.xml file. The error happens everytime I redeploy an application. Right now, the only workaround I found is to restart the server. Then it works fine.

This bug seems to be present for a long time.

I found this thread with the same case:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326552

Any idea that could work apart from restarting the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating your EntityManagerFactorys?  You must maintain their lifecycle by closing them when done.  The issue described in the bug is due to not closing factories, which are statically held and so reused when the app is redeployed.  The old EMF will use the old classloader, and so not work with entities loaded from the redeployed app.

The only way to resolve it is to close old EntityManagerFactory before redeploying.  Alternatively undeploying and waiting for garbage collection to close them before redeploying can work.